# Select the entire row of the lowest price for distinct product

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the below table about products:

```
| id | name   | product_id | price | seller_id | discount_id |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | phone  | 11         | 400   | 7         | 19          |
| 2  | cpu    | 78         | 120   | 33        | 4           |
| 3  | phone  | 11         | 380   | 8         | 22          |
| 4  | phone  | 11         | 460   | 5         | 19          |
| 5  | memory | 80         | 45    | 12        | 16          |
| 6  | router | 98         | 115   | 7         | 16          |
| 7  | cpu    | 78         | 115   | 33        | 66          |
```

I need to select all the columns of distinct product_id with the lowest price. Also to **ORDER** the result by price **ASC**. For this example:

```
| id | name   | product_id | price | seller_id | discount_id |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | memory | 80         | 45    | 12        | 16          |
| 6  | router | 98         | 115   | 7         | 16          |
| 7  | cpu    | 78         | 115   | 33        | 66          |
| 3  | phone  | 11         | 380   | 8         | 22          |
```

I have no problems doing this using **GROUP BY `product_id`** and  **min(`price`)** but I also need other columns (`seller_id` & `discount_id`)

- MySQL version: 5.7.17
- sql_mode=only_full_group_by
- Table is temporary (ENGINE=MEMORY) and can't **JOIN** multiple times

How can I produce the result above from MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a subquery with the min price and join on min price and product.

```
SELECT id, name,product_id,price,seller_id,discount_id FROM t
JOIN
(SELECT tt.product_id,MIN(tt.price) minp FROM t as tt 
GROUP BY tt.product_id)x
ON x.product_id=t.product_id AND x.price = t.price
```

Another option with LIMIT

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM T as TT ORDER BY TT.price ASC LIMIT 1 
WHERE t.id= TT.id)
```

Given that the MEMORY engine is so restricting go the caveman way

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY price),',',1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY price),',',1),
product_id,MIN(price),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(seller_id ORDER BY price),',',1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(discount_id ORDER BY price),',',1) FROM t
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Thank  You Mihai but temporary table cannot join multiple time  "Can't reopen table"

Comment: @h2odev Didnt see the MEMORY engine but,try the last one.

Comment: I'm out of office but I will try that later

Comment: The "caveman way" works! Is not elegant but also is not so slow as I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table with itself (on product_id). As a join-condition add `left.price > right.price` - and then choose the rows, where right.price is null, because for that join, there is no lower right price, meaning the one you have `left` is the lowest:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.product_id, l.price, l.seller_id, l.discount_id 
FROM 
  products l
LEFT JOIN
  products r
on
  l.product_id = r.product_id AND l.price > r.price
WHERE
  isnull (r.price) -- that means: no cheaper price for this position.
```

intermediate result (`SELECT *` no `WHERE`) would look like (shortened):

```
| l.id | l.name    | l.product_id | l.price | r.id | r.name   | r.product_id | r.price
| 3    | phone     | 11           | 380     | null | null     | null         | null 
| 4    | phone     | 11           | 460     | 3    | phone    | 3            | 380
```

Side node: For very large datasets there might be performance-issues, because every additional line of a component would add multiple result rows. i.e. consider another phone:

```
| l.id | l.name    | l.product_id | l.price | r.id | r.name   | r.product_id | r.price
| 3    | phone     | 11           | 380     | null | null     | null         | null 
| 4    | phone     | 11           | 460     | 3    | phone    | 3            | 380
| 5    | phone     | 11           | 500     | 3    | phone    | 3            | 380
| 5    | phone     | 11           | 500     | 4    | phone    | 3            | 460
```

So, if you want to get the lowest price in the past 60 days with daily changes, that will be a huge amount of rows just for "that"... (Actually `60+59+58+...+2+1` I think, cause the most expensive price will produce 59 comparision rows and so on)

Comment: I think with select all field of `left`, you can using `l.*`

Comment: @MrKen If you want all fields, yes ofc.

Comment: Thank You dognose but I have a another issue, the table is temporary and cannot be used multiple times in the query. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Maybe I don't have a SQL only solution for this

Comment: How are you creating the temporary table? Just create two of them `p1` and `p2` works as well.

Comment: Has multiple rows and many updates on it, will reduce the performance :(

Comment: @h2odev i think you should using `CREATE VIEW` in SQL, that can solution for you

Comment: Creata a view instead of a temporary table? Or you have to seek for a no-sql solution.

Comment: I really have to try that. The non-SQL is not a good option. Thank You guys!